# PHPT vs Phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit, phpt

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using one of these two types of tests instead of the other?

*PS*: I'm starting a project that isn't a class or a website.
I have to choose a test system for files and a file may contain only a class, 2+ classes, functions, generic PHP code, etc...

Comment: It does not depend on what your PHP files contain but what you want to test. Depending on that, you can choose the right test-framework. And no, you did not tell enough to give good directions here. And also: What prevents you from using both test-frameworks at once? Your question suggests that you would need to decide between the one or other. But you don't need to.